# Promise rejects before finishing for loop

Tags: javascript, typescript

this might be a easy fix, but I am running into a problem with using a loop with a Promise. I am using Angular and Typescript.

As a backstory, I am trying to implement a very simple user authentication login page. I have a Array of User objects, each object containing a username, password, etc. On the login page, when the user inputs their User/Pass, clicks a "Login" button, a promise function fires which loops through the Array to see if there is a match between the Array and the user input.

Here's some pseudocode that I have written, where `usersList` is the array of Users and `users.username` and `users.password` is the user input.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.usersList.length; i++) {
    if (this.usersList[i].email === user.username && this.usersList[i].password === user.password) {
        resolve({
            /* code */
        })
    } else {
        reject({
            message: "User/Password not found"
        })
    }
```

However, this only works for the first object in the list, since the Promise rejects on the first iteration of the for loop. How would I go ahead and fix this so that it only rejects after the loop has gone through every object in the Array?

Comment: Besides moving the `reject` to outside the loop? You mainly need to keep track if you "found" something or not, then check that *after* the loop to know if you need to reject.

Comment: Your code in english is something like this
`Check first. If it matches, yay, resolve. Else, reject promise. End of lookup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically fix your code by moving the reject.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < this.usersList.length; i++) {
    if (this.usersList[i].email === user.username && this.usersList[i].password === user.password) {
        resolve({
            /* code */
        })
        return
    }
}
reject({
    message: "User/Password not found"
})
```

You need to return to break the loop when found and also, if this code runs in a function, to stop the execution of function.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious problem is you're calling `reject` as soon as one item has been checked and found to not match the input. The loop does continue, but by that point it's too late to `resolve`.

A better idea might be to filter your `users` list to see if the item exists, if it does, `resolve` else `reject`. Something like:

```
var foundItems = this.usersList.filter(u => u.username == user.username && u.password == user.password);
if(foundItems.length){
    resolve({
            /* code */
        });
}
else{
    reject({
            message: "User/Password not found"
        });
}
```

You could also use `find` with similar effect:

```
var user = this.usersList.find(u => u.username == user.username && u.password == user.password);
if(user){
    resolve({
            /* code */
        });
}
else{
    reject({
            message: "User/Password not found"
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Promise reject at first iteration because it did not match the object at index(0) of Array and code inside the else loop executed. To resolve this problem you should write the code where the promise reject at last iteration if it not resolved in all iteration before the last one.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < this.usersList.length; i++) {
    if (this.usersList[i].email === user.username && this.usersList[i].password === user.password) {
        resolve({
            /* code */
        })
    } else if(i === this.usersList.length - 1) {
        reject({
            message: "User/Password not found"
        })
  }
```